# Android httpclient ssl session expires after 10 seconds

Tags: android, session, ssl

Is there a way to make the Cached SSL Session to expire after 60 seconds and not 10?

From chrome dev tools I can validate that our server maintains the session for 60 seconds

I am using a DefaultHttpClient with the following init classes

> SSLSessionCache
>
> SSLCertificateSocketFactory
>
> ThreadSafeClientConnManager

The params are set as follows

> HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 60*1000);
>
> HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 60*1000);
>
> HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(httpParams, false);
>
> HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParams, false);
>
> HttpConnectionParams.setLinger(httpParams, 60*1000);

and i have setKeepAliveStrategy to return 60*1000

and the setReuseStrategy to return true.

Is there any thing else i can do to achieve Chrome's behaivure?

Comment: Not one of those things has anything to do with the SSL session timeout, and you certainly shouldn't be messing with the 'linger' option. Only the SSLSessionCache class is remotely relevant, and I don't see any session timeout properties there. Are you really seeing new SSL handshakes after ten seconds? 10 second sis very low. My server's SSL session timeout is set to ten or fifteen *minutes.*

Comment: Yes i am sure. i have also remote dubug chrome on Android  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging and have seen it performe a handshake every 10 seconds.